# Is there a preferred Java version for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Got a new, 64 bit Windows 7 computer.  Computer is a refurbished Dell Inspiron, 8 Gig ram, 4 core I3 processor.  Installed 32 bit Java on it, and minecraft hangs after 5-10 minutes of play.

Is there a preferred version of Java?  Or do you think it's something other than the JVM that's the problem?

Comment: Knowing your computer setup would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the version bundled with Minecraft installation.

This is the version the game was tested with, and any other may have some incompatibilities or unoptimal ways of doing things, versus what Mojang found to be working and debugged against. The launcher automatically sets up the game to work with it - don't change it unless you have a valid reason and know what you're doing.

Comment: I changed the accepted answer to this one.  If memory serves correctly, "back in the day" the JVM wasn't bundled, or if there was one installed on the machine it just used it.  I think that's changed.  So, the accepted answer can change.

Answer (score 6):

You should almost certainly switch to the 64-bit Java version - it's going to be much better on 64-bit Windows 7.

Either OpenJDK 7 or the [latest Oracle Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) should be fine. I use the Oracle one, YMMV.

The other thing that *might* cause a problem is graphics drivers (since Minecraft uses OpenGL). It's worth making sure you have the latest driver updates for your graphics card. This has solved various gaming-related issues for me in the past.

Comment: Java 64-bit has been known to cause **all sorts** of issues in Minecraft.  Even with the latest release, Minecraft crashes for me after about 15 minutes when playing on 64-bit JVM, even with render-distance set to "near."  JVM 32-bit works fine.

Comment: Installed Oracle 64-bit 1.7, and it's working much better.  Slightly more laggy, and different rendering bugs than my 8 year old 32-bit XP box.  :(

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft What sort of issues has it been "known to cause"?  Mosts OSs ship the 64bit OpenJDK7, and that's all I've ever used; never had any issues whatsoever.

Comment: @Hugo: See my second sentence...

Comment: "crashes for me" and "known issues" are completely different things. I've played minecraft for hour and hours each day, constantly staying up to date, and have never had any crashes in almost a year and a half.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing minecraft on several computers and several different OSs with no issues.
I've always used 64bit OpenJDK 7.

Is there any particular reason for using 32bit java on a 64bit OS?

Also, have you tried running from a terminal (cmd?) and see if there's any output when minecraft crashes?

Comment: Only installed 32 bit because apparently IE 9 is a 32 bit application??  So the default java install was 32 bit.  Manually installed the 64-bit version.  Running much better.

Comment: @John The optimised version of IE9 runs 32bit, the 64bit version isn't optimised yet (ie it runs as slow as IE8).

Comment: Not sure why there's a downvote...

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Oracle java 32bit on my a6-4400m and had to turn "fast graphics" to "normal". I also decreased particles no v sync to get a decent 50-60 frames.

I just realized I was using 32bit. I installed 64bit Java now I'm running maxed with 60-70 fps and it's not stuttering. But 2 stacks of TNT takes it down to like 5 fps.